# Can I use function in lambda RuleFor?

Tags: c#, .net, fluentvalidation

In documentation

> To specify a validation rule for a particular property, call the RuleFor method, passing a lambda expression that indicates the property that you wish to validate.

does that mean that i must write in lambda only properties ?

Can i use extension method IsSomeCheck() ?

Is it more code style for RuleFor or it critical?

```
 RuleFor(x => x.IsSomeCheck())
              .NotEqual(true)
              .WithMessage("Some Text!");
```

For example, I have

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    bool BeAverageHumanAge()
    {
      return (Age >= 0 && Age <= 100);
    }
}
```

So

```
RuleFor(x => x.BeAverageHumanAge())
              .NotEqual(true)
              .WithMessage("Some Text!");
```

Is it illegal?

Comment: Doing it like this: RuleFor(x => x.IsSomeCheck()), you are not declaring which object or property will be validated. You can do something like this RuleFor(e => e.FirstName).IsSomeCheck().

Answer (score 1):

Within the lambda of the `RuleFor` method, we specify the property over which we want the validation to take place. For example,
Consider a class called Person-

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

If you wish to validate the age of the `Person` instance, you can write the rule as follows:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Age)
              .GreaterThan(0)      // in-built validator method
              .WithMessage("Age must be greater than 0");
```

Suppose you wish to add some custom check for age, then you can write your own method for this. Something like this:

```
bool BeAverageHumanAge(int age)
{
    if(age >= 0 && age <= 100)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

This method can be used for the validation of age something like this:

```
RuleFor(x => x.Age)
              .Must(BeAverageHumanAge)      // invoking custom validation method
              .WithMessage("Age does not lie in average human age range");
```

Comment: thanks. i`m extend description with example. Is it illegal?

Comment: @gen32 what u are trying is not illegal. The `RuleFor()` will give u `true` or `false` and that will get passed to `NotEqual(true)`. It should work fine. However, the idea of having rules is to facilitate the validation for classes that contain only properties (the ones which are our request models) and avoid having to write validation logic within the class itself. So definitely a bool property telling the same thing would be preferred over a method I believe.